# Linking to CSS/JS file using the websites absolute URL

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, absolute-path

I am wondering what the best method is. E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= GetBaseURL() %>Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

renders

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any danger or performance hit doing it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any danger or performance hit doing it this way?

No. Whether you specify a relative or an absolute URL doesn't matter: It will be translated into an absolute URL by the browser anyway.

Using an absolute URL has an upside: It makes it easy to move all static resources to a different server if necessary (e.g. to follow Google's page optimization rules). It's a good thing to have if the variable is available.

Answer (score 1):

You could even use the relative url starting from the web root:

```
/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js
^-- note the slash at the beginning
```

gets always translated to the same path on the server, no matter in what directory your page resides: in other words, whether the document is at `http://example.com/some/path/index.html` or `http://example.com/index.html`, the browser will resolve `/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js` into `http://example.com/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js` - using only the protocol and domain of the base document, ignoring the path.

Comment: No good if the site is hosted in a virtual directory unfortunately.

Comment: @Jamie Carruthers: I'm afraid I don't quite catch your drift - care to elaborate? The browser doesn't distinguish how the site is hosted. It takes the document's domain (e.g. `www.example.com`), prepends the protocol (`http://`) and appends the path (`/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js`).

Answer (score 0):

not at all. the browser resolves it to that at the end of the day anyway.